# Listen for events from other Cocoa Applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there any way to (in Cocoa) listen for specific, generic events occurring in other concurrently running applications?  That is to say, can I listen for when another application open, saves, closes, quits, etc?  Do Mac applications broadcast a certain set of generic events that I can listen for?

Alternatively, if my application is not in focus, could I listen for certain key-stroke commands, like cmd-o (for open), cmd-s (for save), cmd-w (for close), cmd-q (for quit), etc, as a backend way of listening for events in other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something simpler than distributed objects (suggested by Neilvert), you could use distributed notifications from the distributed notification center. However, these are not posted unless you built the application. For monitoring when applications start or quit, you can use NSWorkspace and its notification center. These notifications are sent for every application which appears in the dock.

Comment: I know I can use NSWorkspace to look at currently running programs (and listen for them opening or quitting), but I'm wondering if I can listen for other events too, such as saving.  I don't have access to these programs, they are other established applications - for instance, is it possible to listen for when a user saves in Photoshop or Preview?  I don't want to alter these applications in anyway - just listen for generic events.  Or is it possible to just listen for a cmd-s key event when my application doesn't have focus?

Comment: They don't create events, and you can't trust the cmd-s listener (a lot of people don't use shortcuts). In 10.6, you can register to listen for changes to the file system.

Comment: Ah, interesting approach, when it comes to saving, at least.  I'll look into that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider Distributed Objects. See reference link [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html).